# Submit button not working in Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I launch ChromeDriver or IEDriver and click the submit button (manually and automatically), it does not send the inputs. It works outside of webdriver though, I can click the submit button and send the inputs but in webdriver, it doesn't seem do anything. Is this something wrong with webdriver?

Thanks.

Note: The selenium version is the latest 2.47.0 along with chrome and chromedriver. I can't provide the link to the webpage since its a private server. Here is the code for the button

```
<span id="button-1429-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center" unselectable="on">Submit All</span>
```

Comment: Can you add more details like selenium version.ie version,chromeversion, iedriverserver version,chromedriver version, And is it possible to provide the link for the webpage.or html code for the button.

Comment: The selenium version is the latest 2.47.0 along with chrome and chromedriver. I can't provide the link to the webpage since its a private server. Here is the code for the button...<span id="button-1429-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center" unselectable="on">Submit All</span>.. Thank you

Comment: are you using sencha extjs application.If yes which version of extJS

Comment: what's the selector you used [xpath]

Comment: We're using extJS 4 and I used //span[text()='Submit All']

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having the same issue. Using `element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)` solves it for me.

Answer (score 2):

It will solve, Here I'm using python language.
First, you need to import Keys and the following code will help you.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
login_btn=driver.find_element_by_id('button-1429-btnInnerEl').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:-

**step 1.** `import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;`

**step 2.** `driver.element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`

Answer (score 0):

*Try to click it with javaScript:*

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//span[contains(@id, 'button-1429')]"));

 var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;
 js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work for me. Thanks though

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Comment: there is no exception, the test passes but it doesn't actually submit anything. When I look at the test, I can clearly see selenium interacting with the button but it doesn't actually submit anything.

Comment: Did you inspect the element and typed 'Submit All' in search box to double check if there is only one element with that text. Because if it is not that might be one of the reasons why the button is not being clicked?

Comment: I'm only seeing one the element show when I search using the xpath in the console. Good point though. I'm thinking it may have something to do with extjs 4?

Comment: Don't know never faced that sort of problem before. Is maybe your element inside of iframe or frame?

Comment: No, it's not in an iframe or frame. The other guys on my team can't solve the problem either. Thanks though, let me know if I can provide some more details. I can't send a link to the site since it's behind a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Submit All')]")).click();
```

Comment: can you please add proper explanation for better understanding

Comment: I have used customized xpath which finds an element which contains Text "Submit All" and then click on it. If you want xpath with id or name please share the code of the button, which will be definitely starting with <button> or <input> tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Action Class. Might be Button is in Displayed false.

```
IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.Id("submit")); // locate the button
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(button).Click().Perform();
```